# CaliburnMicro - Invoke method on resolve

Tags: wcf, caliburn.micro

I'm using caliburnMicro on my WPF application.

Beside being UI application, it is also Inter Process communication server (We use `WCF` over named-pipe).

Each service host is registered as singleton (`container.RegisterSingleton(typeof (IMyServiceHost), null, typeof (MyServiceHost));`).

Where each implementation of `IMyserviceHost` holds `WCF` `ServiceHost` property.

In current state each service host object request has to open the channel in code after resolving the object.
I want each service host request for resolve will trigger the `Open()` of the `ServiceHost` property in order to open the server side channel (this is from the IPC server side).

Is it possible using the exist Caliburn Micro methods?

The registration code:

`container.RegisterSingleton(typeof (IMyServiceHost), null, typeof (MyServiceHost));`

Then resolve code:

```
//Resolve the object
var serviceHost = IoC.Get<IMyServiceHost>();
//Then open the channel
serviceHost.Instance.Open();
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at handler registration in the [`SimpleContainer`](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Simple%20IoC%20Container&referringTitle=Documentation) docs. This allows you to register a func. Essentially you can register something like this:

```
() => {
   var serviceHost = IoC.Get<IMyServiceHost>();
   serviceHost.Instance.Open();
   return serviceHost;
}
```

This would assume that you already added `IMyServiceHost` in the normal manner, that way we can request it with activation or without.

Another option is to do it globally. In the advanced features of the same document you can set up a global activation hook which can do advanced initialisation on any object, simply do a type check and if it is `IMyServiceHost` then call your required method before returning the object.

Comment: Hey Dean, this is me. I felt free to edit your answer a bit to improve the formatting. Glad to see you back.

Comment: It's good to be back :) Fatherhood tends to take over your life somewhat. Cheers for the edits, looks much better!

Comment: @McDonnellDean what do you mean "added IMyServiceHost in the normal manner"?

Comment: I mean leave your singleton registration there, you need a second registration if you want to go the add handler route